# Get mp4 file tags

Tags: php, mysql, html, file

I would like to know how to get mp4 file content in php.
For example: get the name of the song,the released date of song ,duration,file name,extension,artist,genre,album and size.Add then store it into a database.Please help.

Comment: Limit your question to just getting meta data about a given mp4 file.  Don't personally know how to do so, but that will be the hard part.  In regards to storing the information, it is easy and you could figure out that part with a search or two.

Comment: Thanks so how can I collect the metadata from the mp4 file in php.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: You really mean mp4-audio, not mp3 .?.

Comment: @VolkerK  Can it be done with mp3?  I expect it would be done either client side with mixed results or with some sort of command line linux program.

Comment: Can be done with either file format in php. e.g. mp3: [ID3 Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.id3.php), mp4: [php-mp4info](https://code.google.com/p/php-mp4info/) - but I haven't used any of them, so no idea if they really work or not ;-) There are also some Q+As here on SO regarding php and mp4 tags, so this is most likely a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have a lot of options like;

**1. [php-mp4info](https://code.google.com/p/php-mp4info/)**

A simple PHP class to read MP4 meta data from MP4 based files, such as MP4, M4V and F4V.

---

**2. [php-reader](https://code.google.com/p/php-reader/)**

PHP Reader is a well documented small library written in PHP to read and write media files and their information headers in an object-oriented manner. Currently supported formats are ASF (Windows Media Player files, ie WMA, WMV, etc), ID3, including both ID3v1 and ID3v2 (MPEG files, ie MP3), MPEG Audio Bit Stream (ie ABS, MP1, MP2, MP3), MPEG Program Stream (MPEG movies, and DVD and HD DVD video discs, ie MPG, MPEG, VOB, EVO), and ISO Base Media File Format (eg QuickTime, MPEG-4 and iTunes AAC files, ie QT, MOV, MP4, M4A, M4B, M4P, M4V, etc).

---

**3. [getID3()](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/)**

getID3() is a PHP script that extracts useful information (such as ID3 tags, bitrate, playtime, etc.) from MP3s & other multimedia file formats (Ogg, WMA, WMV, ASF, WAV, AVI, AAC, VQF, FLAC, MusePack, Real, QuickTime, Monkey's Audio, MIDI and more).

---

**4. [PHP based MP4/F4V meta data reader](http://www.tommylacroix.com/2009/06/11/mp4-and-f4v-php-flash-video-meta-data-reader/)**

The MP4Info class is a simple extensible PHP class reading the MP4 container’s frames (called boxes) to get various information, namely the video duration, the video/audio codecs, the width and the height, as well as the embedded XMP meta data.