# PHP: How to read the metadata of m4v, avi, mkv, mp4

Tags: php, metadata, media, mp4

I am trying to read meta data for some different video formats (m4v, avi, mkv, mp4) using PHP.

I was hoping I could get some small example of how to do this.

I was looking around and I saw a some suggestions for PHP-Reader. I don't want to use Zend Framwork unless it is the only way to do it, and the versions without Zend don't have any examples of how to use it, and I wasn't able to figure it out myself.

I tried a built in PHP function, but I think it doesn't with the formats I want it in.

```
$path = 'I:\\Movies\\21 Jump Street {mp4}.mp4'
$meta_data = get_meta_tags($path, true);


echo '<pre>';
echo 'meta_data: ';print_r($meta_data);
```

Comment: i think you are misusing the `get_meta_tags()` function..

Comment: `get_meta_tags()` is for HTML, not images. The function you want is `getimagesize()`

Comment: also, if you are talking about reading such files, try [apache tika](http://tika.apache.org/) or something equivalent.

Comment: Does [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34689928/2057709) help you?

Comment: @VC.One Yes it does thanks!