# How do I extract metadata from videos in PHP?

Tags: php, video, metadata

I am trying to extract metadata information from a directory of videos which are stored on my computer, I have done so for images previously in PHP using code such as the following to read in the image

`$imagePath = './videos/timelapse.mp4';

 $exif_exif = read_exif_data($imagePath ,'EXIF' ,0);`

However exif_read_data only works for images. How can I go about reading metadata from videos in Notepad++

Can anyone help me with this problem please? appreciate any given help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get mp4 file tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689518/get-mp4-file-tags)

Comment: "This function is an alias of: exif_read_data()." "exif_read_data() reads the EXIF headers from an image file. This way you can read meta data generated by digital cameras. "  http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: Im giving an example of me extracting metadata for images, how would I do this for videos in Notepad++?